# How can I encourage dwarfs to make babies?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my current fort, I had just 2 migrant waves, and then they stopped coming (I guess, because the civilization died - I got a proper warning before embark).

I decided this would be a good setting to have a use for babies, which are usually just a nuisance. However, several years have passed, and there is no sign of babies.

I even chose 2 dwarves, and turned off all their labors, so they spent a few years socializing, listening for stories, etc. Still no sign of babies. (BTW I used Dwarf Therapist to make sure they have proper sexuality; also, one of them "dreams of making a family" - come on, do it!)

I currently have 7 dwarfs (after some deaths in construction accidents), 5 male and 2 female. What can I do to encourage babies in my fort?

Comment: Light a few candles, a little romantic music, some wine...

Comment: Yet another title that is amazing out of context.

Comment: @Svj0hn If the title is on Arqade, that's all the context that's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [DF wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Marriage), dwarfs can become married only if their age is close enough (10 years difference). In my case, that left only 2 possibilities for a couple.

Removing all labors from the 3 candidates made them proceed in the right direction: in a few months, they became friends, then lovers, and maybe more than that in future.

Answer (score 4):

Considering how few females you have, you'll want to check if they have husbands who are dead - dwarves are fiercely monogamous.  Other than that, you'll just have to wait until they marry someone, or if they are married already turn off their labors and those of their spouses.

However, with only two breeding pairs you are going to have to be careful not to run out of valid mating pairs.  As I recall, when I investigated this before dwarves would refuse to mate with any direct family members (parents, siblings, children), but anyone else was fair game, so you have some leeway, but don't lose all your females to !!FUN!!.

Answer (score 3):

Socialising!

Setup a meeting zone (you may decide you want it inside to avoid !!FUN!!) and make sure dwarfs have some idle time to just hang around with each other. They'll all congrate in the meeting zone and this is when the magic can happen :)

Eventually you'll be overflowing with babies (infact with only 2 females it's going to take awhile).